# How can I manipulate this data set to give a new column?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks like

```
ID  retailer    
1   A            
2   A               
1   B              
3   C                
3   B
```

What I would like is a data set with a column for each distinct retailer indicating if the ID is associated with the retailer (something like a boolean would do fine).

I could do this manually with `proc sql` but that doesn't generalize well when I have a lot of retailers.

Is there anyway to create a pivot table with SAS?  I know proc tabulate can do something similar, but I need the output for further calculations.

```
Desired output:

ID  A  B  C      
1   1  1  0
2   1  0  0
3   0  1  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS can't really do pivot tables, but you can certainly swap your rows for columns using the transpose procecure - as follows:

```
data have;
input ID $ retailer $  ;
retain count 1; /* NOTE - this bit is necessary to have in your source */
datalines;
1   A            
2   A               
1   B              
3   C                
3   B 
;
run;

/* sort to enable transpose */
proc sort; by id;run;

/* transpose data */
proc transpose data=have out=want (drop=_name_);
  by id;
  id retailer;
run;

/* turn missings into zeros */
proc stdize data=want reponly missing=0;
run;
```

[image: example result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  When I run your code on my data, the proc tranpose returns an empty table.  Any idea why that may be?

Comment: do you get any warnings or errors in the log?  Maybe start a new session..  If you've had errors, sometimes the system `option obs` is set to zero.  The code does work on the sample data provided.  Did you sort your input table by ID?

Comment: No errors in the log.  Started a new session, still empty table.  Yes, I sorted the input table by id.

Comment: sounds obvious, but did you reference your table in the `data=` part of the transpose procedure?  Also, are you sure your input table has records?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to resolve the issue on my own.  I added a column of ones to the data set.  It returns what I would like now.

Comment: aah yes - that was the `retain count 1` part in the sample data bit above,  apologies, should have highlighted (have done so now)